# Raphael.js and height of document

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I create a canvas with

```
var paper = Raphael(domid);
...
paper.height = 600;
paper.width = 600;
```

After I draw path, a part of it is invisible (as it's beyond the edge of canvas). But if I do

```
var paper = Raphael(domid, 600, 600);
```

Everything is OK. What is the essential difference between second and first pieces of code?

Comment: what version of Raphael are you using? I don't see references to setters for `width` and `height` on the paper object in the current version (2.1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rapheal doesn't have setters for `width` and `height` on the Paper object, so calling them is not affecting the DOM, but just setting some properties on the Paper object.

Passing in the `width` and `height` params in the constructor will affect the SVG tag in the DOM.

If you want to change the paper's width and height after constrcution, you can set the style properties of the SVG tag like so:

```
var paper = Raphael(domid);
paper.canvas.style.width = '200px';
paper.canvas.style.height = '100px';
```

As Kevin mentioned, it's probably better to use the `setSize` method to handle runtime resizing.

eg)

`paper.setSize(200,100)`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Directly modifying the dimensions may be necessary in some circumstances, but it might not be a bad idea to call `paper.setSize` -- that would let Raphael manage itself gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's possible another solution: `var paper = Raphael(domid, '100%', '100%');`.